# How to migrate postgresql database tables along with Sequence

Tags: amazon-rds, database-migration

noAs the both source and target PostgreSQL are 13.3 version, it's AWS RDS DB. DMS only copy the table not the sequence. I would like to migrate the sequence as well.

Comment: What is DMS? How do you copy the data?

Comment: DMS, Data Migration services is tool in AWS which will help to migrate the data from one database to another Database. it's copies only tables AWS confirms too. hence struck with missing Sequence.

Comment: in other looking for best option to copy sequences from one DB to another DB

Answer (score 1):

[This library](https://github.com/sinwoobang/dms-psql-post-data) is for you. AWS DMS does not provide the things except data. You need to do it manually, or use an automation script like the linked one.